# Get Row Additions/Deletions from same MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following employee table and I want to know who left/joined the company based on the "Month", "Quarter" and "Year" as per the output shown below.

From the data we can see that Olivia left the company in Q1 of 2017 and Geogia and Grace joined the company in Q2 of 2017

**Employee DB Table**

```
| Month | Quarter | Year | Company | Company Description | Employee ID | Employee Name | Country Description |    
| M1    | Q1      | 17   | 020     | US                  | 03237       | Jessica       | UNITED STATES       |
| M1    | Q1      | 17   | 020     | US                  | 05153       | Olivia        | UNITED STATES       |    
| M1    | Q1      | 17   | 020     | US                  | 06809       | Hannah        | UNITED STATES       |    
| M1    | Q2      | 17   | 020     | US                  | 03237       | Jessica       | UNITED STATES       |    
| M1    | Q2      | 17   | 020     | US                  | 0680        | Hannah        | UNITED STATES       |    
| M1    | Q2      | 17   | 020     | US                  | 08434       | Georgia       | UNITED STATES       |    
| M1    | Q2      | 17   | 020     | US                  | 08858       | Grace         | UNITED STATES       |
```

**Desired Output**

```
| Month | Quarter | Year | Company | Company Description | Employee ID | Employee Name | Country Description | Status |    
| M1    | Q1      |   17 |     020 | US                  |       03237 | Olivia        | UNITED STATES       | Out    |    
| M1    | Q2      |   17 |     020 | US                  |       08434 | Georgia       | UNITED STATES       | In     |    
| M1    | Q2      |   17 |     020 | US                  |       08858 | Grace         | UNITED STATES       | In     |
```

I'm trying to use the following statement but I'm stuck

```
SELECT  t.month,
        t.quarter,
        t.year,
        t.employee_id,
       t.employee_name

FROM q4_16_hc AS t
JOIN q4_16_hc AS t1
  ON t1.employee_id = t.employee_id
WHERE t.month <> t1.month
group by t.employee_id
```

Comment: "From the data we can see that Olivia left the company in Q1 of 2017" - How do you see that? Fist occurance = join - Last occurance = leaving?

Answer (score 0):

You would normally do this using a `full join`. As MySQL doesn't support it, you should do a `union all` with a `left join` and `right join`.

```
--Employees who left from previous quarter
SELECT t1.month,
    t1.quarter,
    t1.year,
    t1.employee_id,
    t1.employee_name,
    'Out' as status
FROM q4_16_hc AS t1
LEFT JOIN q4_16_hc AS t2 ON t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id AND t1.year = t2.year 
AND t1.Company=t2.Company AND t1.quarter='Q1' AND t2.quarter = 'Q2'
WHERE t2.employee_id is null 
UNION ALL
--Employees who newly joined 
SELECT t2.month,
    t2.quarter,
    t2.year,
    t2.employee_id,
    t2.employee_name,
    'In'
FROM q4_16_hc AS t1
RIGHT JOIN q4_16_hc AS t2 ON t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id AND t1.year = t2.year 
AND t1.Company=t2.Company AND t1.quarter='Q1' AND t2.quarter = 'Q2'
WHERE t1.employee_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes very close to what you want:

```
select x.*
from ((select t.employee_id, t.employee_name,
              min(concat_ws(':', year, quarter, month)) as yqm,
              'in' as which
       from q4_16_hc t
       group by t.employee_id, t.employee_name
      ) union all
      (select t.employee_id, t.employee_name,
              max(concat_ws(':', year, quarter, month)) as yqm,
              'out' as which
       from q4_16_hc t
       group by t.employee_id, t.employee_name
      )
     ) x;
```

You can use `substring_index()` or `substr()` to extract the year, quarter, and month if you really need those in separate columns.